# reordering mysql table rows to increase speed

Tags: mysql, optimization, rows

I have a mysql table which has a bunch of words. Clearly some words are more common than others, thus they will be `SELECTed` more commonly.

At the moment the table is ordered alphabetically, however, if I were to order the rows based on the frequency/commonness of the word and make sure there's a `LIMIT` on all my queries, would that make `SELECTs` faster overall? (Given that common queries will be faster)

I mean 'hard' reorder the rows, not `ORDER BY` in a query.

Some basic info about the table:

```
Row         Statistics
Format      dynamic
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Rows        106,827
Engine      myISAM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create an index on the column which holds the words you SELECT by. Otherwise MySQL will always scan the entire table.

Comment: I have that already. So ordering them by their commonness and limiting the SELECT to 1 will not speed up the query? Even though it might read fewer rows before finding the right row? I have a feeling the index might change the way the query 'searches' so my point is missing the mark

Comment: I'm quite sure that when you have an index, the order of the rows in the actual table does not matter. That's the point of indexes after all - MySQL does not have to search through the table row-by-row, but can just look up in the index where the selected rows are located.